# html - how can I display images when option from drop down menu is selected

Tags: html

I have the code for a drop down menu:

```
</center>
<p>
<center><select>
  <option value="none">None selected</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
</center></select>
</p>
```

I want to be able to display an image of a cat (such as http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/95142833-crate-training-cat-632x475.jpg) when the "cat" option is selected and also alternate text (such as "image of cat could not be loaded") if the image could not be loaded. How can I do this?

Comment: You would do this by adding some Javascript that adds/changes an image when an option is selected. Have you tried anything? Do you want us to write your code for you?

Answer (score 3):

you can insert an image on value change in select box, i would do it like this:

html:

```
<select id="pic-changer">
  <option value="none">None selected</option>
  <option value="cat" data-picture="cat.png">cat</option>
  <option value="dog" data-picture="dog.jpg">dog</option>
</select>
<div id="image-location></div>
```

jquery (javascript) code:

```
$('#pic-changer').change(function(){ //if the select value gets changed
   var imageSource = $(this).find(':selected').data('picture'); //get the data from data-picture attribute
   if(imageSource){ //if it has data
      $('#image-location').html('<img src="'+imageSource+'">'); // insert image in div image-location
   } else {
      $('#image-location').html(''); //remove content from div image-location, thus removing the image
   }
})
```

if you dont need the select box value, I would suggest putting the picture link in there:

```
<select id="pic-changer">
  <option value="">None selected</option>
  <option value="cat.png">cat</option>
  <option value="dog.jpg">dog</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code becomes:

```
   $('#pic-changer').change(function(){ //if the select value gets changed
   var imageSource = $(this).val(); //get the selected value
   if(imageSource && imageSource != ""){ //if it has data
      $('#image-location').html('<img src="'+imageSource+'">'); // insert image in div image-location
   } else {
      $('#image-location').html(''); //remove content from div image-location, thus removing the image
   }
})
```

You can do much more with javascript and jQuery i suggest you learn it, it ain't hard at all. http://jquery.com/

Comment: i gave him some room to try this out and give him some motivation to learn javascript & jQuery

Comment: You done a Good Job...But what you are thinking will not work out..Anyway no problem..Sry if i hurt you.

Comment: I get your reasoning, but sometimes its good to give a working example to show what can be accomplished to make people intrested to learn it for themselfs, if he will post another identical question i would give the same answer as you did

Comment: You've spelt the jquery/javascript function wrong. i get undefined function because HMTL SHOULD BE HTML. Editing now

Answer (score 2):

You asking Something which is not Possible by Simple HTML.

In Addition Of HTML Code you should use JavaScript.

I suggest you to Start learning Javascript.

here is the Link. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/

Lean it.. Implement it. You will reach your Goal.

All The Best..!!